# Does bnd launcher support configuration files that are made known with system properties?

Tags: java, osgi, bnd

When I launch an application from bndtools (using a file `launch.bndrun`), I can specify `-runproperties: java.util.logging.config.file=jul-debug.properties`, with `jul-debug.properties` being a file in the working directory. Everything is fine and works as expected, i.e. the java.util.logging properties are read from my configuration file.

When I create an export (`launch.jar`) using this `lauch.bndrun`, the configuration file `jul-debug.properties` is not included in the `launch.jar`. Can I add some instruction to `launch.bndrun` that causes the `jul-debug.properties` to be included in `laucn.jar` in such a way that `jar -jar launch.jar` will cause the configuration file to be evaluated?

I looked through all the `-run...` instructions for bnd, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Did you try -includeresource?

Comment: Apart from embedding the config the question is if java util logging would find the config at runtime if it is inside the jar.

Comment: @bj-hargrave: tried that, but `-includeresource` doesn't have any effect in `launch.bndrun`. And it's no good to have the file in one of the bundles. Of course, Christian is right. Maybe I should restate the question: is it possible to include a file (such as `jul-debug.properties`) in the generated export jar that is copied into the working directory set for the application on startup (configured with `-runstorage`, right?).

Comment: `-runstorage` is NOT a working directory for your application to use. It is a working directory exclusively for the OSGi Framework. You should not store arbitrary files there, though you can ask OSGi to store files safely there by calling `BundleContext.getDataFile`.

Comment: To (hopefully) answer the actual question... no, the JAR exporter does not include anything in the exported JAR except bundles and the launcher code. Without writing an exporter plugin, I don't know of a way to get additional files in there.

Comment: `-includeresource: jul-debug.properties` in the bndrun file works when creating an executable jar: https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/ddf9ff1ff6d0513e818d212d0ea3f4c7435b2f9a/biz.aQute.launcher/src/aQute/launcher/plugin/ProjectLauncherImpl.java#L227-L243. But launch does not package a jar, it launches in situ.